# How to make contenteditable div content as text only

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, contenteditable

I am looking for a way to make contenteditable div return me text only data. How can this be achived in a cross browser manner.

The default behaviour gives me html text. And pasting text from browser into "contenteditable div" also paste the html text.

I would like "contenteditable div" to behave just like a text pad with plain text only.

Comment: How about using a `<textarea>` element?

Comment: For usability issues like scrollbar and autoresize, i would like to stick to "contenteditable div"

Comment: use a regex to strip out the html?

Comment: @Pete Every time a person paste's html content, it renders it. So users expects formatted content to be stored on save. So, stripping out html might not work all that well here.

Comment: Why not strip it out when it is pasted then? Or html encode the text so the tags get rendered as text

Comment: That can be done but i feel that its an overhead. If only i could do that in a simpler manner.

Comment: Parsing html to get text, i might end up getting unwanted data in my final text.